# orientation() / fullScreen() crashes the app with Processing Android Mode

Tags: android, processing, orientation, fullscreen, android-fullscreen

If I call orientation() or fullScreen() in setup() while using Android Mode for Processing, the app crashes as soon as it starts on the device after running the setup() twice.  This never happened with other SDKs, Processing version, Android Mode version or devices. What is the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Use this outside of setup():

```
public void settings() {
fullScreen();
orientation(LANDSCAPE);
}
```

and just to be sure, download Android Mode 0250 from https://github.com/processing/processing-android/releases

(most recent Android Mode for processing is a failure in terms of compiling.  I will always keep a copy of 0250 so if the link becomes unavailable, contact me and I will send you my copy)

Comment: I had this problem and solved it absolutely by chance so I am posting this thread in case any one else has the same problem.